# Is it possible to execute code after return statement in C++?

Tags: c++

I am a java programmer, new to C++. In the code below, I know if( condition1 ) is true variable1 is returned. But is there any mechanism by which the second if is also processed after the first if condition evaluates to true? I am asking this because I have seen code like this and I found it while debugging.

```
if( condition1 )
{
    return variable1;
}

//do some processing here

if( condition2 )
{
    return variable2;
}
```

*EDIT*: For those of you wondering what is this question about? This is what I have seen when I was debugging in MS Visual Studio. It appeared like the debugger went right after "return variable1" to next statement, but in fact I believe the code returned and then came again to next line in a blink ! I was like what just happened why it would go to next "if" after returning "variable1". So there, it was all me wondering what Visual Studio was doing.

Comment: Depends on whether `condition1` is true or not.

Comment: Not if the statement is executed. `return` means that you are returning from the current function and leaving its execution

Comment: As long as you don't return on the first if, then yes can continue

Comment: It's executed if `condition1` is false. What are you _really_ asking?

Comment: All please see the edited question

Comment: So what do you want to return if both conditions are true?!

Comment: You should post the exact conditions, I have the feeling that the conditions are exclusive causing the surprise, but that you have undefined behavior and that is causing the issue...

Comment: *So there, it was all me wondering what Visual Studio was doing.* - code did not compile after a change, but VS allowed you to debug the previous version, probably after asking a question. Then it was showing what's running based on line numbers, that did not fully match with the ones in the non-compiling code.

Comment: @tevemadar absolutely! that's what might have happened.

Answer (score 28):

Although there is a way to run code after the return statement, there is no way to change the return value after a return statement has been executed.

Here is how you can make some code to run after a return statement:

```
struct AfterReturn {
    ~AfterReturn() {
        // This code will run when an AfterReturn object goes out of scope
        cout << "after return" << endl;
    }
};

int foo() {
    AfterReturn guard; // This variable goes out of scope on return
    cout << "returning..." << endl;
    return 5;
    // This is when the destructor of "guard" will be executed
}

int main() {
    cout << foo() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The above program [prints](http://ideone.com/Pijpfw)

```
returning...
after return
5
```

Comment: This is genius. I'm trying to make all debug output in a certain function yellow, and this idea lets me accomplish it using RAII.

Answer (score 5):

No.  Once a `return` is encountered, nothing else in the function is processed.

Comment: Not totally true. As suggested by @dasblinkenlight, destructors of local variables are yet to be called after the `return` statement is encountered.

Comment: Looks to me like the OP was asking if the second if condition would be executed. It will not.

Answer (score 4):

Your function must execute 1 and exactly 1 `return` statement.

So, either `return variable1` gets executed or `if(condition2)`, but never both.

Comment: I believe OP is asking whether it's executed *when `condition1` is true*.

Comment: @KyleStrand op edited his question after i posted my answer.  I have since edited my answer to match

Answer (score 1):

No, code is never executed after a `return` statement is reached. If, however, `condition1` is false, then the `return` statement isn't reached, so execution proceeds normally. This is exactly the way Java behaves, too.

There is an argument against early `return` statements, but personally I find them helpful; trying to avoid them can lead to extraneous cruft, such as temporary variables that don't really do you any good or large `if`-blocks that are mostly just confusing to read due to their scope.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember (or at least as my teachers told me) is not quite a good idea to use `return` *before* the end of the execution, with the exception of recursive functions.

I suggest you use a variable to store the value you want to return as a result of your function and return it at the end of your function:

```
if( condition1 )
{
    ans = variable1;
}

/* more code */

if( condition2 )
{
    ans = variable2;
}
return ans;
```

Comment: I've heard that too, and personally, I disagree. It's a style preference, and if you build your functions to be small and readable, having a `return` statement early is very easy to follow, and will prevent unnecessary code from firing, and also prevent a bunch of unnecessary nested blocks.

Comment: @JoeEnos Thank you for your feedback. Maybe in this case it could be cleaner to do something like `if(21) { return v1; } else if(c2) {/*code*/ return v2;}`

Comment: I personally usually prefer getting return statements out of the way earlier so I don't have to indent later code.

Comment: @Barranka That's how I would do it personally. There are exceptions of course, like if I wanted to potentially log or debug the value, but if it was a simple method with this kind of layout, I'd return early. FYI: The `else` in your comment is unnecessary - `else` only fires if the first one isn't true - if the first one is true, it will return, so that second `if` will never fire if the first one is true.

Comment: This is called Single Entry, Single Exit. This originated from C, where using return would not do the final things, like deallocating resources used in a function, so people were using goto. This rule makes no sense in C++ (there are destructors) and Java (there is `finally`), but some people still do it.

Answer (score 0):

It only is executed if it is called. At which point, you are leaving that function/method. 
In your case, if condition1 is false, it will run your extra processing and then proceed to test condition 2.

Now, in your case, your code probably won't compile. (I know it wouldn't in Java) 
This is because it is possible to have neither condition be satisfied in which case we get lost. So, you should probably have some return outside of your if statements.

In short, no execution of code happens after a return is called.