# Is it possible to write statements after return?

Tags: c++, function, program-entry-point

Is the `return` statement the last statement inside `main` or is it possible to write statements after return?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << "Hello" << endl;

    return 0;

    cout << "Bye" << endl;
}
```

This program compiles but only displays "Hello".

Comment: `This program compiles but only displays "Hello".` I would be surprised otherwise. FYI, this applies to every function, not just `main`.

Comment: Well what do you expect this program to do?

Answer (score 4):

> is it possible to write statements after return?

It is possible and valid to write more statements after the return. With gcc and Clang, I don't get a warning, even with the `-Wall` switch. But Visual Studio does produce `warning C4702: unreachable code` for this program.

---

The [`return` statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return) terminates the current function, be it `main` or another function.

Even though it is valid to write, if the code after the `return` is unreachable the compiler may eliminate it from the program as per the [as-if rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if).

---

You could have the `return` statement executed conditionally and you could have multiple `return` statements. For example:

```
int main() {
    bool all_printed{false};
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
    if (all_printed) 
        return 0;
    cout << "Bye" << endl;
    all_printed = true;
    if (all_printed) 
        return 0;
}
```

---

Or, you could use a `goto` before and after the return and some labels, to execute the `return` statement after the second output:

```
int main() {

    cout << "Hello" << endl;
    goto print;

return_here:
    return 0;

print:
    cout << "Bye" << endl;
    goto return_here;
}
```

Prints:

```
Hello
Bye
```

---

Another solution, linked to in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50027391/1460794), would be to use RAII to print after the return:

```
struct Bye {
    ~Bye(){ cout << "Bye" << endl; } // destructor will print
};

int main() {
    Bye bye;
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
    return 0; // ~Bye() is called
}
```

Comment: `You would need a goto before and after the return` No, he wouldn't. It's useless to write useless code.

Comment: @DimChtz How else?

Comment: `..to avoid the return statement` But you don't avoid the return statement. You still print before the `return` statement.

Comment: @DimChtz Sooo, you don't like `goto`?

Comment: I don't like useless code. Just write: `cout << "Hello\nBye\n"; return 0;`

Comment: @DimChtz In your example the `return 0;` is useless because `main` will add that for you. Perhaps we shouldn't be too harsh?

Comment: @DimChtz But that doesn't really answer the question or demonstrate how `return` statements can be placed arbitrarily within a function. Its not about the best way to achieve the output, its about how `return` works.

Comment: @Galik Still his example with the `goto` is useless and makes no sense (at least for me).

Comment: @DimChtz The sense behind the answer it to demonstrate how `return` works. That is the point of the program. It wouldn't be doing its job if it didn't show how `return` works (in the middle of) a function.

Answer (score 1):

> is return statement the last statement inside main or is it possible to write statements after return?

The run time behavior of executing a `return` statement is independent of the function. Be it `main` or some other other function, when a `return` statement is executed, nothing after that is executed in the function.

It is possible to write statements after the `return` statement. They are superfluous since they are not executed. A smart compiler might be able to even omit creation of object code corresponding to the statements after the `return` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can write statements after a return like in your example, but they will never be executed, and some compilers will give you a warning "unreachable code" (For example 
[C4702 in VS2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c26da40e.aspx)).

To execute code after a return statement, see [Is it possible to execute code after return statement in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15822626/2436175)

Answer (score 0):

Such code is usually generated in the intermediates debugging stages while narrowing the window to capture a bug. It works but must be fixed by the programmer asap.

Answer (score -1):

The only way you could usefully have code after a "return" is if the "return" statement is conditional.

```
if (error) return 0;
# All code invoked past this point knows error is false
```

This isn't great coding style, you're creating code where there are 2+ ways to exit.  When you need to debug it you'll find it more challenging to put in flags and "what happened when we exited" and so forth.

Comment: -1 because early returns are perfectly fine. I'll take ten `return`s over ten nested `if`s or ten modifications to that dreaded `ret` variable any day.

Comment: @antonio Your edit is correct, but so was my answer and given his level of understanding he may not have seen "if" before.

Comment: @quentin There are situations where it's perfectly fine, ten nested ifs being a good example.  General rules are made to be broken in specific instances.  However the general rule is it should be avoided.

Comment: @DarkMatter If you want it to be more explicit, I would suggest using curly brackets